# Creating new sheet overwrites existing sheet created via openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a bar chart directly in excel, using a pandas dataframe. In the same output excel, I'd like to save in a separate sheet the original csv used for the bar chart. My code:

```
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
    ws = wb.active 

    for row in dataframe_to_rows(new_df, index=False, header=False):
        ws.append(row)

    chart = BarChart()
    values = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=ws.max_row)
    labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=ws.max_row)

    chart.add_data(values)
    chart.set_categories(labels)

    ws.add_chart(chart, "E2")

    wb.save("~/barChart.xlsx")
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("~/barChart.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Source_data")
    writer.save()
```

The problem I get is the the last three lines, which overwrite the produced bar chart. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):
ExcelWriter can also be used to append to an existing Excel file:

```py
    with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_3')
```

Comment: Thank you, the 'a' was what I was missing.